# Gmail & Yahoo - offline mail viewer for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, email, gmail

Two part question:

I am having a difficulty regarding receiving my mail. I have 3 Gmail accounts & 1 Yahoo account. In Windows, I use Microsoft Outlook or Outlook Express. What email client can I use on my Mac?

The second part is that my system administrator has banned accessing Gmail and Yahoo mail via their websites. Is it possible to still access it anyway?

Comment: in gmail you could always forward mail to another email... so you could create a windows live mail or something and forward your mail to that provided the administrators don't ban windows live mail either... :)

Comment: Yeh ! That's a great idea.

Comment: What if I said that I was the Sysadmin in question? Perhaps I should ban Windows Live *and* SuperUser... `['}` ... ... ... I'm not, but it would have been funny.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OS X has [Mail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_%28application%29) built into it.

Attempting to bypass a site block could get you in trouble. That being said, you could proxy or start an SSH tunnel. Please search SU because there are multiple other questions pertaining to circumventing a block.

Answer (score 2):

With Mac OS X you can use Mail.app or use one of the open source Mail clients such as Mulberry, Thunderbird, etc. or pay to use one like Entourage (part of Microsoft Office).

Yahoo depending on the account most often provides POP access, while Gmail offers both IMAP and POP access. See their respective sites for how to configure them with your email client. (eg. [Gmail with Mail.app](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81379))

Comment: `...See their respective sites for how to configure them with your email client....` is a bit problematic as `...my system administrator has banned accessing Gmail and Yahoo mail via their websites....` Which probably means that the documentation is inaccessible.

Comment: @Moshe: Google Cache? Some mail clients assist with setting it up (eg. Mail with GMail) anyway.

Comment: Google Cache?

Comment: @Moshe: One method of avoiding blocked sites and/or accessing content when the site is down is to use Google's Cached version of a page. Either by searching `cache:URL_HERE` or clicking the Cache link.

Answer (score 1):

To enable POP in Gmail with Apple Mail:

> - Sign in to Gmail.
> - Click Settings at the top of any Gmail page.
> - Click Forwarding and POP/IMAP.
> - Select Enable POP for all mail or Enable POP for mail that arrives from
>     now on.
> - Choose what to do with your messages after they're accessed with
>     your POP client or device.
> - Configure your POP client* and click Save Changes

To configure your client:

> - Enable POP in Gmail. Don't forget to click Save Changes when you're
>     done.
> - Open Apple Mail.
> - Click Mail, and select Preferences...
> - Open the Accounts tab, and click the plus sign (+) along the bottom to
>     add a new account.
> - Enter your name in the Full Name: field.
> - Enter your Gmail address in the Email Address: field.
> - Enter your Gmail password in the Password: field.
> - Check the box next to Automatically set up your account.
> - Click on Create.
> - Now you're done! Your settings should now look like this:

I don't have Yahoo and I'm not in the mood of searching their docs now.

Good luck!

PS:

Thunderbird may be an alternative if Sysadmin learns about Mail. It runs on Windows and OS X.  http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/